# How can sed find pattern in one field but append another(same row)

Tags: linux, sed, bash-scripting

I have a text file that has comma separated values.
Field1 has field that needs to be matched, but field two needs substitution based on the match.

Example:

A,C
B,C

Result:
A,D
B,C

I'm guessing command would look more or less like:

```
sed 's/A/D/'
```

Thank you

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: @glennjackman dude, if you try 's/A/D/' it obviously doesn't do quite what he wants. He knows that he just thought the solution would be based on that general idea. And he's right.. i'd say rather than replace A with D, it's replace A,blah with A,bleh. so match the first part and mention both the parts in the replacement, leaving the first part as is, and making the second part different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
$ echo A,fgfdgd|sed -r 's/A,[^,]*/A,D/'
A,D
```

If the first column is A, and then there is a comma, and there is whatever in the second column, it replaces the lot with A,D. This will only happen when it matches A in the first column(followed by a comma and whatever in the second column).

An example with a file

This turns your example into your result. So, where your first column is A, your second column becomes D.

```
$ cat a.b
A,C
B,C


$ sed -r 's/A,[^,]*/A,D/' a.b
A,D
B,C


$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an address expression to select the lines you want to edit, then use a regular replacement to actually do the replacement.  A fun thing about sed is that, prior to the "s" command, you can specify a line number or a regular expression to pick the lines you care about (the address can also be a comma-separated start and end that specify all lines contained within the "address range", but leaving the second part out selects single lines).

In your address expression, look for "not a comma, followed by what you want".

In the replacement, remember the stuff before your pattern, then put the "before" parts before your replacement string.  You remember the "before" part because you want the before stuff to only include one comma, no more and no less.  Here it is showing that it matches the first field and only impacts the second; I'm replacing "la" with "moo" in the second column of lines that match "atter" in the first column.

```
$ echo -e "pattern,blah,aaa\npattern,bleh,stuff" | sed '/[^,]*atter/s/\(^[^,]*,[^,]*\)la/\1moo/g'
pattern,bmooh,aaa
pattern,bleh,stuff
```

This alone will not work right with escaped commas in fields, so hopefully your CSV file is simple. :)

Comment: you say in your first line "Use a range expression" but did you? i'd think a range expression is two addresses separated by a comma. an address can take the form of a regex, but for it to be a range I think it has to be two addresses like '/regexp/,/regexp/s/a/b'

Comment: It's an "address range" expressed in the form of a single address - which is arguably just a very short short range.  I used unclear terminology, and forgot to go back and fix it after that dawned upon me. :)  It's edited now.

Comment: looking in the sed manual, the term "address expression"(that you used in your last edit)  doesn't exist. there is an address, and an address range. you used an address, though as you say in your edit, an 'address range' can be used. In your comment you write  'It's an "address range" expressed in the form of a single address'  I don't think that's correct terminology. Looking at the manual, I don't see that one address being called a range. A range must be two addresses.

Comment: The phrase "address expression" is referring to an address defined by a regular expression.  Try running `sed '/barlow'` and look at the error message; it says "address regexp", which is shorthand for "address regular expression".

Comment: Regarding a range, in the sed documentation a single address is referred to as a "singleton".  A "singleton" is a set with one element.  The address is thus a tuple with a cardinality of 0, 1, or 2.  A range does not need to be two different addresses (`sed -n '1,1'p behaves the same as `sed -n '1p'`), so it seems reasonable to consider the singleton case as syntactic shorthand for a range where the start and end points are identical.  Which is how it's implemented by match_address_p in the source.

Comment: That paragraph in the manual that uses the term "singleton addresses" uses the general term "address specification" to refer to an address range, a singleton address, or a null address. You could interpret "singleton address" as a set with one address and 'null address' as no address specified.And If 'address' was defined as you claim then it'd be a recursive definition. Consider this line "An address range can be specified by specifying two addresses separated by a comma (,)." <-- singleton. + the definition of an "address regular expression"  /regexp /  again singleton is assumed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13161/discussion-between-barlop-and-dannysauer)